# How to use ADO.net (SqlConnection) in ASP.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3 and could not find a sample that uses `SqlConnection` with MVC3 to connect to an existing database. All the samples I found like MusicStore and others are using EF.

Comment: Show us what you've tried working on.

Comment: Actually I am trying to retrive data and display it in a grid and when user click select it will display details. I know how to do that in Winform but trying to learn MVC3 and do the same thing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Read through [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3) tutorial; it shows you exactly how all of the ORM stuff works so you can get going quickly.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use SqlConnection? MVC3 is supposed to  be used with Entity; that's kind of the point.

Comment: I am using a complicated sql query with lot of joins and may use temporay tables as well.

Comment: I do not think I can use Temporay tables with Linq.

Comment: Is there an alternative to Temporary tables in Linq?

Answer (score 0):

From your contour call off to your repository pattern object ex ICustomerRepository.

Your repository calls your data access layer which returns some data transfer object (or some choose a domain object ie Customer)
Then your view model is populated from that object.

Some choose to chop out the transfer objects and send domain objects to the view rather than view models but the recommended approach is view models.

Your sqlconnection code goes in your data access layer. Do not stuff this code into your controller.

Comment: Is there any sample availbale regarding what you expalained please?

Comment: Specifically which part? Are you looking for help with sqlconnection code or repository pattern or.....